# Finite Elements 3D

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

Does anyone knows how to solve the Laplace equation in a Sphere domain and with the following boundary conditions:
[image]

Consider alpha=0. 
I have tryed the following code, but i don't belive the boundary conditions are right(solution zero in all external boundary). I would also appreciate if anyone could please show me a good way to plot the solution in 3D.
Thanks in advance!

```
mesh = DiscretizeRegion[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}]];
op = -Laplacian[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] - 2
Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], 
  D] = {DirichletCondition[u[x, y, z] == 0, Norm[{x, y, z}] >= 1]}
uif = NDSolveValue[{op == 0, Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], D]}, 
  u, {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh]
Plot[uif[x, 0, 0], {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Try `DirichletCondition[u[x, y, z] == 0, True]`

Comment: I run your code and get this message: `NDSolveValue::femnfm: The current version of NDSolve cannot solve equations over boundaries or surfaces. Please specify a region where the embedding dimension is the same as the dimension. `

Comment: @rewi, OP -- Try discretizing as a boundary mesh, or substitute `Ball` for `Sphere`. Diogo, assuming you're getting the same errors as rewi, it's helpful to others to include them in the question.  (If not, that's strange.)

Comment: @rewi i cant reproduce your error. In my computer there is no error mesages...I using  Mathematica 10 on Windows 8.

Comment: @Michael E2 `Ball` was the key. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you all! I think it is working @rewi. Does anyone knows a nice way to see the solution together with the mesh?

Comment: @Diogo You might be interested in this Q, since it deals with a difficulty I encountered trying to help with visualizing the solution to your PDE: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102506/how-to-scale-values-for-colorfunction-in-slicecontourplot3d

Comment: @Michael E2 Nice link!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

may be this is your answer

```
mesh = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Ball[{0, 0, 0}]];
op = -Laplacian[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] - 2;
Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], D] = {DirichletCondition[u[x, y, z] == 0, True]};
uif = NDSolveValue[{op == 0, Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], D]}, u, {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh]
```

**Addendum**

I add the picture

```
Show[Plot3D[uif[x, y, 0], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}], reg] // Quiet
```

[image]

Comment: You can also use `SliceContourPlot` to visualize, but see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102506/how-to-scale-values-for-colorfunction-in-slicecontourplot3d for a possible bug.