# How to scale values for ColorFunction in SliceContourPlot3D?

Tags: plotting, color, mesh

Trying to help out in the question, [Finite Elements 3D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102500/finite-elements-3d#102502),
I came across this behavior of [`SliceContourPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SliceContourPlot3D.html):

```
op = -Laplacian[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] - 2;
uif = NDSolveValue[{op == 0, DirichletCondition[u[x, y, z] == 0, True}, 
   u, {x, y, z} ∈ Ball[{0, 0, 0}]];

SliceContourPlot3D[
 uif[x, y, z], "CenterPlanes", {x, y, z} ∈ MeshRegion@uif["ElementMesh"], 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The range of colors does not go all the way down to violet/indigo.  I expected the range of colors to be something like this:

```
With[{sel = Positive[uif["Grid"].{0.3, -0.4, -1}]},
 With[{pts = Pick[uif["Grid"], sel]},
  Graphics3D[
   GraphicsComplex[
    pts,
    {Point[Range@Length@pts, 
      VertexColors -> (ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Rescale[Pick[uif["ValuesOnGrid"], sel]])
      ]}
    ]]
  ]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Is this a bug in `SliceContourPlot3D`?  (Perhaps it's due to extrapolation from sampling outside the domain?)  Is there a way to get it to rescale the colors the way I expected?

I'm using V10.3.0, Mac OSX.

Comment: Looks that `SliceContourPlot3D` is a function of Mathematica 10.3.0. To me it is not working. I'm using 10.0.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems `SliceContourPlot3D` makes an initial sample, that is not quite right - i.e. outside of the region. Using

```
op = -Laplacian[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] - 2;
uif = NDSolveValue[{op == 0, 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y, z] == 0, True]}, 
   u, {x, y, z} \[Element] Ball[{0, 0, 0}], 
   "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {(Indeterminate &),
              "WarningMessage" -> False}];

SliceContourPlot3D[
 uif[x, y, z], "CenterPlanes", {x, y, z} \[Element] 
  MeshRegion@uif["ElementMesh"], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

On a related note, I am wondering if for FEM this `ExtrapolationHandler` should be the default - what do you think?

Comment: I almost always use this extrapolation handler, because in my uses of interpolation, extrapolation is usually inappropriate.  Not sure if turning off the warning message by default is the best choice or not.  Plotters suppress such warnings automatically, it seems.  Sometimes, it might be good to be warned.

Answer (score 4):

```
mesh = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Ball[{0, 0, 0}]];
alpha = 0.;
op = -Laplacian[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] - 2
Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], 
   D] = {DirichletCondition[u[x, y, z] == 0, True]};
uif = NDSolveValue[{op == 0, Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], D]}, 
  u, {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh]
sol2 = Plot[uif[x, 0, 0], {x, -1, 1}]
SliceContourPlot3D[
 uif[x, y, z], "CenterCutSphere", {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "BrightBands", 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]